# Symfony2.5 dynamic connections

Tags: symfony, dynamic, doctrine, connection, entitymanager

I'm wondering what the best and most up-to-date solution is to have dynamic connections for the symfony2 entity manager? Specifically for symfony 2.5 or future.

So from a controller, something like:

```
$this->getManager()->switchConnection($db_name,$db_user,$db_pass);
```

I know that there are some solution floating around using reflections or connection wrappers, but I was wondering if anything newer/simpler has emerged?

Comment: There always has been http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Comment: Yes I've seen that page many times however it only explains basic configurations which force you to manually list in advance the databases and connections you want to use. This is fine, but I would like to dynamically create new databases and new connections. Essentially a system that would allow user-specific databases.

Comment: Ahh, I get it now. :) It is possible, but of course requires manipulation of the Dependency Injection Configuration, which is quite advanced. A compiler pass may have to be created.